# Getting Error in MapVIew - Invalid Coordinates - Beginner

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit

I  have a 2 tab application. One of those tabs loads the Map View, and it points to a few coordinates (Annotation pin points). All of this works properly.

But when i keep on clicking the first tab and second continuously i get the following error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid Coordinate -180.00000000, -180.00000000'
```

I don't have a coordinate like that, but this only comes when i keep on clicking the tabs continuously. How can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem when switching tabs in my app. I fixed the problem by validating the coordinate before assigning it to MKMapView. I did the validation with the following snippet:

```
if (-90.0f <= coordinate.latitude && coordinate.latitude <= 90.0f &&
    -180.0f <= coordinate.longitude && coordinate.longitude <= 180.0f)
{
   // assign the validated coordinate to MKMapView
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to use the **CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid** property. It will return true if coordinate is correct or false instead.
For example:

```
if (CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(yourCLLocation2D)) {
    //coordinate is correct
} else {
    //wrong coordinate
}
```